# Windows 7 | Apache Reverse Proxy configuration

Tags: apache, windows-7, reverse-proxy

I'm having problems with setting up a very basic ReverseProxy in Windows 7 and Apache 2.2

I have a virtual machine registered to a private IP address that I'm wanting to reverse proxy to from the host environment.

Note that for the current iteration of trying to work through this, I'm trying to reverseproxy from foo.bar.baz:* to foo.bar.com:6284

The relevant host entry is foo.bar.com
(assume that bar.com is the corporate domain)

Added

```
127.0.0.1       baz.bar.com
192.168.59.103   foo.bar.com
127.0.0.1        foo
```

Inside my Apache httpd.conf file (only including the delta for this change...deltas seem to escape some people, so I thought I'd call that out directly.),

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

<VirtualHost *>
   ServerName foo.bar.baz
   ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
    </Proxy>
   ProxyPass / http://foo.bar.com:6284
   ProxyPassReverse / http://foo.bar.com:6284

</VirtualHost>
```

If I attempt to browse directly to foo.bar.com:6284, I get the expected results.  Hosts resolves the name to the private IP and I see the markup that I expect.  But when I attempt to browse to foo.bar.baz, I get "No Response from DNS Server."

Can anyone see what's wrong with my supposed-to-be-stupid-simple reverseproxy?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so assuming that my corporate domain name is bar.com, everything seems to route fine as long as all host entries that reference "bar" always followed it with ".com"

If I tried to enter `foo.bar.net` or `foo.bar.org` or `foo.bar.floop` as my host, I get "No Response from DNS Server"  errors.  If I enter `foo.bar.com` the host resolves.

While I received these errors as "Vital Security Proxy Errors", a developer on my team that is helping me test this received Trustwave errors instead.

This seems to be something specific to our network security policies.